# linq create index with select

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query:

```
var query = (from x in be.tblEntries
             select new { x.Entry_PK, x.EntryStatus }).ToList();
var results = query.Select((index, x) => new { index, x });
```

which basically creates an index columns, the problem with this is  that it creates two dimension array like this:

```
{Index=1,{ Entry_PK = 32432, x.EntryStatus  =true}}
```

Is there a way I make it append the index into the one dimensional like this:

```
{Index=1, Entry_PK = 32432, x.EntryStatus  =true}
```

Comment: You should use `AsEnumerable` rather than `ToList` to indicate that a particularly LINQ method should be performed using LINQ to objects rather than through a query provider.  It accomplishes the same goal while maintaining deferred execution, allowing the results to be streamed, removing the need to load the entire data set into memory, and removing the need to create and populate a list that is entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of selecting the object, select its properties like:

```
var results = query.Select((index, x) => new { index, x.Entry_PK, x.EntryStatus });
```

If your collection is an in memory collection then you can do:

```
var query = be.tblEntries
              .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, x.Entry_PK, x.EntryStatus })
              .ToList();
```